# Strange Behavior of C exit()

Tags: c, exit

I am trying to exit my main function with a certain exit number, but it always exits with 0. For example, the code:

```
printf("command exited with error: %i\n", commandExitError);
if(commandExitError > 0)
  exit(commandExitError);

if(openError > 0)
  exit(openError);
printf("I shouldn't see this if there was an error");
return 0;
```

has the strange behavior that if `commandExitError` is 0, but `openError` is 1, then it exits with error 1. However, if `commandExitError` is greater than zero, it still exits with 0! For example, this is some output with `commandExitError > 0`:

> command exited with error: 512

Note that we never reached the print statement "I shouldn't see this...." Then, getting the exit status of my program, echo $?

> 0

We see that my program still exits with 0 although it should clearly exit with 512.

Comment: Please copy the exact terminal commands and output.

Comment: The exit value is an 8-bit quantity — `512 % 256 == 0`.  Try 513, 514, 3, 4, 133, 134, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

according to [man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html)

> The exit() function causes normal process termination and the value of `status & 0377` is returned to the parent

octal 377 is decimal 255

```
512 & 255 = 0
```

Comment: you beat me by 30 seconds :( good ansewer though :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the range of possible exit codes is defined by any standard, but the GNU C library (as an example) only accepts values in the range 0 to 255.  [Reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html)